# Determine if a string is in an array using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code:

```
function checkIfUnitCostItemsAreZero(finaliseIDList)
{
    var selectedItems = finaliseIDList;
    selectedItems = $.makeArray(selectedItems); //array is ["-2,-3"]
    var getItem = $("#builderItemsList .listItem");
        for (i = 0; i < getItem.length; i++)
        {
            var currentItem = ($(getItem[i]).attr("key"));
            if (currentItem.indexOf(selectedItems) > -1) 
            {//currentItem = "-2" then "-3"
                var unitCost = $(getItem[i]).attr("unitcost");  
                console.log(unitCost);
                unitCost = parseFloat(unitCost);
                if(unitCost==0.00)
                {
                    return true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    return false;
}
```

selected item currently equates to the following:

```
selectedItems = ["-2,-3"]
```

And further down, currentItem is evaluated at:
`"-2"`, and the next loop `"-3"`.

In both instances, neither go into the `if` statement. Any ideas why?

Comment: Guess you've a mistake in your array. It should be `selectedItems = ["-2", "-3"]`.

Comment: I think your whole strategy is incorrect, you should look for `currentItem` in `selectedItem`.

Comment: Please change the if condition to this and let me know the result: `selectedItems.indexOf(currentItem) > -1`

Comment: Could you by any chance provide a few more information? At least what does `finaliseIDList`provide exactly?

Comment: have provided the answer below. Both your suggestions really helped.

Comment: Comparing floats for equality is not advised.

Comment: Javascript provides a built in method on array object that is more suitable that indexOf. array.includes https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes

Answer (score 0):

Courtesy of Hossein and Aer0, Fixed using the following:

String being passed in as a single value. Use split to seperate it for array.

Modify the if clause.

```
function checkIfUnitCostItemsAreZero(finaliseIDList)
{
    var selectedItems = $.makeArray(finaliseIDList.split(','));
    var getItem = $("#builderItemsList .listItem");
        for (i = 0; i < getItem.length; i++) {
            var currentItem = ($(getItem[i]).attr("key"));
            if (selectedItems.indexOf(currentItem) > -1)
                {
                    var unitCost = $(getItem[i]).attr("unitcost");  
                    unitCost = parseFloat(unitCost);
                    if(unitCost==0.00)
                        {
                        return true;
                        break;
                        }
                }
        }
        return false;
}
```